# Get the stock quantity of each active variation in WooCommerce variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

I need to show stock quantities of each variations of a variable product in Woocommerce

I use this code to show stock quantity:

```
<?php echo $product->get_stock_quantity(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

Now I have this product:

Shirt has Red , Blue for variable product.

> "Red Shirt" has a stock quantity of **3** 
> "Blue Shirt" has a stock quantity of **4**

so I need to show:

> **Blue = 3 // Red = 4**

How can I do it?

Comment: Your question not very clear, can you please try to explain it better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a variable products with different color variations and stock quantity by variation.

So you need to get for each variation:
- the variation stock quantity:
- the attribute 'pa_color' term name for this variation

Assuming that you already get the `WC_Product_Variable` object `$product`, here is the code:

```
if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )){

    // Get the available variations for the variable product
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    // Initializing variables
    $variations_count = count($available_variations);
    $loop_count = 0;

    // Iterating through each available product variation
    foreach( $available_variations as $key => $values ) {
        $loop_count++;
        // Get the term color name
        $attribute_color = $values['attributes']['attribute_pa_color'];
        $wp_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $attribute_color, 'pa_color' );
        $term_name = $wp_term->name; // Color name

        // Get the variation quantity
        $variation_obj = wc_get_product( $values['variation_id'] );
        $stock_qty = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity(); // Stock qty

        // The display
        $separator_string = " // ";
        $separator = $variations_count < $loop_count ? $separator_string : '';

        echo $term_name . ' = ' . $stock_qty . $separator;
    }

}
```

> This will exactly output something like *(the color name "=" the stock quantity + separator)*:
>
> **Blue = 3 // Red = 4**

Tested and perfectly works in WooCommerce 3+

Comment: Thank you! But I have one problem! in other product I received this error: **Fatal error: Call to undefined method WC_Product_Simple::get_available_variations()**

Comment: @AlirezaDarvishi **Updated my answer:** You just need to filter with `if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )){ // the code }`

Comment: Hi! I cant showing Blue and Red. woocommerce need to any options or slug?

Comment: @AlirezaDarvishi I have answer in your other question. Please have a look to it. For your table output I have the correct code.

Comment: Where would this code be placed in order to work? Which template file?

Comment: @rpeg it depends on what do you want to do with it… It can be placed in a template or in a hooked function. What is your problem or needs?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it needed to go in the functions.php. I'll place in template file then. However I'm looking at template files like stock.php and wondering if there's particular one I should use.

Answer (score 4):

```html
 global $woocommerce, $product, $post;
// test if product is variable
if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) 
{
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    foreach ($available_variations as $key => $variation) 
    { 
$variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
         $variation_obj = new WC_Product_variation($variation_id);
         $stock = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function to get values from database.

The product stock quantity values are stored in **wp_postmeta** table.

```
$stock = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_stock', true );
```